# App Badge Icon Still Shows After Invite Declined

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit

in my Game Center based turn based game I am currently having issues with the app icon badge count. When I decline an invite to join a game, the badge count still shows 1 notification.

I have even tried using `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0` which works until the game is re-launched and the game matches are loaded.

The icon shows as 1 even though there are no matches whatsoever. It's only removed if a new match is started.

Comment: Where are you calling `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber` ?

Comment: I call this after the completion of the decline invite process.